# how to limit camera rotation like a human head

Tags: unity-game-engine

controller cam and rb of player

```
public void controladortrajeCamLibre(){///camara libre
    Vector2 md = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse Y"));  md = Vector2.Scale (md, new Vector2 (sensitivity * smothing, sensitivity * smothing));
    smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.x, md.x, 1.0f / smothing);
    smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.y, md.y, 1.0f / smothing);
    mouseLook += smoothV;
    cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
    character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
```

Comment: Try using codeblocks...  There's a button for it, looks like {}...  Then, ask a question ;)

Comment: Check any Unity FPS tutorial, the controller usually do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to limit the rotation of the camera.